# How can I calculate the active setting?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB with 3 collections. Here are the 3 collections each with an example of a document it contains:

`tag`

```
_id: ObjectId('61b873ec6d075801f7a97e18')
name: 'TestTag'
category: 'A'
```

---

`computer`

```
_id: ObjectId('6098c5ab615d9e23543d0f6f')
name: 'TestComputer'
category: 'A'
tags: [
    'TestTag'
]
```

---

`setting`

```
_id: ObjectId('61e56339b528bf009feca149')
name: 'FirstSetting'
category: 'A'
priority: 1
tags: [
    ObjectId('61b873ec6d075801f7a97e18')
]

_id: ObjectId('61e56339b528bf009feca150')
name: 'SecondSetting'
category: 'A'
priority: 2
tags: [
    ObjectId('61b873ec6d075801f7a97e18')
]
```

The idea is that you can create a **tag** and tag your **computers** and **settings**, but only within the same category:

*Example: A tag of category 'A' can only exist in computers and settings of category 'A'*

A computer can only have one active setting at a time. The active setting is the one that shares the same tag. And if the device share tags with multiple settings, the one with the highest priority wins.

So based on those rules, I would like to add a new ***activeSetting*** property to each of my devices, like this:

`computer`

```
_id: ObjectId('6098c5ab615d9e23543d0f6f')
name: 'TestComputer'
category: 'A'
tags: [
    'TestTag'
]
activeSetting: ObjectId('61e56339b528bf009feca149')
```

**What I've tried:**

I've tried to use `lookup` to get a list of computers and a list of settings of each tag, but I don't really know where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

```
db.computer.aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: ObjectId("6098c5ab615d9e23543d0f6f")}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "settings",
      localField: "category",
      foreignField: "category",
      pipeline: [
        {$sort: {priority: 1}},
        {$limit: 1},
        {$project: {_id: 1}}
      ],
      as: "activeSetting"
  }},
  {$set: {activeSetting: {$first: "$activeSetting._id"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bmX70--pmRC)